# Azure Traffic manager gives SSL error while App gateway URL works while using Azure App gateway ingress controller on AKS

Tags: ssl-certificate, kubernetes-ingress, azure-aks, azure-application-gateway, azure-traffic-manager

We are going multi-region for our project and there is a need for us to use an Azure traffic manager to route traffic to each region. Our setup looks like below where our app gateway is exposed via a public IP which I used to configure on the Azure Traffic Manager.

[image]

My issue is when I hit the traffic manager URL it give me an SSL cert error, while if I hit the App gateway URL directly it works fine on HTTPS. Looking at the below error I know I need to configure the traffic manager certificate and my question is

1. Is this needs to be configured somewhere in the traffic manager? OR
2. DO we need to configure this in the application gateway and change the app gateway ingress in Kubernetes with and also use traffic manager certificate there?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

•   The traffic manager works at the DNS level, thus as the DNS records pointing to the traffic manager’s public URL aren’t setup correctly, you are getting this error when browsing the traffic manager’s URL. Also, when you are accessing the application gateway URLs independently, they are being accessed successfully as the URLs for the application gateways are hosted on the Azure DNS and independent public IPs are also allotted against their DNS records. Thus, appropriate DNS records to route the DNS access request for the traffic manager’s website need to be updated.

•   Since you are using multi region setup in Azure with load balancing features, I am considering that your custom domain and its DNS records are setup in Azure itself. And the URLs for the application gateway are setup as separate endpoints in the form of subdomains in the custom DNS record setup itself. Thus, when you browse the application gateway URLs according to the custom domain URL setup, you can access the application page correctly. With respect to the traffic manager, **you will need to create a CNAME record pointing from your custom domain to the ‘*.trafficmanager.net’ domain, while also creating a CNAME record pointing from your custom domain to your generic application gateway URLS.**

•   Once done, **create A host records for each application gateway endpoint pointing to the public IP address assigned by Azure to them.** After doing the above, your traffic manager URL should be able to route and redirect the application access requests correctly. For more information, please refer to the community discussion below which specifies the exact details relating to your problem: -

[Azure Traffic Manager SSL Setup (not classic)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38162252/azure-traffic-manager-ssl-setup-not-classic)